# Switch two file names?

Tags: unix

Is there a way in unix to easily/automatically switch the filenames of two files?

Files:

- file1
- file2

want to switch the file2 to be named file1, and file1 to be named file2

Answer (score 1):

```
>mv file1 temp
>mv file2 file1
>mv temp file2
```

Comment: Use `-i` on the first one to be safe.

Comment: you could create a script for it. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987303/how-to-swap-filenames-in-unix